# Is it possible to localize the title of EKSource?

Tags: ios, localization, calendar, eventkit

There are a table view to display all native calendar source title and calendar title in my app, here is my code to get the titles:

```
    NSArray <EKSource *> *nativeCalendarEventSources = self.eventStore.sources
for (EKSource *ekSource in nativeCalendarEventSources)
        {
            NSSet<EKCalendar *> *ekCalendars = [ekSource calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

            // We import sources if it has non-zero calendars.
            if (ekCalendars.count)
            {
                NativeCalendarAccountSource *localSource = [NativeCalendarAccountSource findOrCreateWithIdentifier:ekSource.sourceIdentifier
                                                                                              managedObjectContext:context];
                localSource.title = ekSource.title;
                [sourcesToBeDeleted removeObject:localSource];
                for (EKCalendar *ekCalendar in ekCalendars)
                {
                    NativeCalendarAccount *localCalendarAccount = [NativeCalendarAccount findOrCreateWithIdentifier:ekCalendar.calendarIdentifier
                                                                                               managedObjectContext:context];
                    localCalendarAccount.title = ekCalendar.title;
                    localCalendarAccount.source = localSource;
                }
            }
```

But I found that the title : "Other", "Subscribed Calendars" are not localized,
Is there any way that we could localized it?